# regarding xsd schema defination of type attribute in response xml

Tags: java, xsd, jax-ws

Thanks for your time , newbie in java,

```
 <address type="sponsor">
                <fullAdress>
                    <street>Blah blah</street>
                    <country>Blah blah</country>
                </fullAdress>
            </address>
```

this is what my end user xml would be , i was little confused about attribute type over here.. what would be xsd definition?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from what you asked, my understanding is that you are asking about the types of your attributes. I have not used XSD extensively but here is what I *think* you are looking for.

```
<xs:element name="fullAddress">
 <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Obviously there is more setup involved with the file itself (This would be a snippet) as far as declarations and such are concerned. But as you can see I specified both the street and country attributes as String types.

Hope this helped. :)